# Buying a car as a freelancer - Business costs

Tags: tax-deduction, car, germany

I am a freelance software developer, and I am thinking of buying a car, which I would probably use every now and then for personal matters, but mostly for business related trips.

What are the conditions that have to be met, so that the car be categorized as business assets?

**PS:** I live in Germany, so it would have to follow the German law

Comment: I would advise seeing a tax adviser in your country and asking them.  If your income does not warrant hiring such a person, then perhaps it would be better to not use the business to buy the auto.  Here in the US, if your income is high enough, a few hundred spent hiring a tax adviser, translates to thousands saved in taxes.